# Percent Formula Field using MAX function (for single field)

Tags: formula-field, percent, max

I am trying to create a custom formula field (Percent) off of another custom formula field (Number) that self references the Number field to find the highest (MAX) value and to convert the Number field/values into Percent.

Current Custom Formula Field (Percent) created:

```
Average_Daily_Eligible_Submissions__c / MAX(Average_Daily_Eligible_Submissions__c)
```

However, the results seem to indicate the formula isn't calculating as expected.
The range of average daily eligible submissions (number) goes from 0 to 1.
The record with average daily eligible submissions = 1 should return 100% (which is happening) but record with average daily eligible submissions = 0.7 (as an example) should return 70% as in 0.7/1 (ie. 1 being the max value). However the later returns 100% too currently.

Any idea how to fix this formula/or how to use MAX function appropriately?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I realize that the reason it's returning 100% for all record is because it's looking at the current record's values (rather than retrieving the highest value across multiple records)

Comment: this is a report formula?

Comment: No, it's a formula field I am trying to create on the Contact object. My goal is to convert a Number field (already existing on Contact object) into a % field (where the % is calculated in relation to the highest/max value of the said Number field, across all contact records). I want to know what % each contact record represents against the highest (contact) record/value.

Comment: I'm confused formula fields can't reference multiple records of the same object.

Comment: I am finding this out now ah! I am clearly learning! Do you have any idea how I could store (dynamically) the highest value of a field (across all records of a single object), maybe using flow? If I could store this (max value) number on all individual records (find the max value > update a field on the contact record), I could then create my formula field using the fields of the single record. Not sure if what I am saying is clear enough ah!

Comment: Across all Contacts? Or across all Contacts per Account parent?

Comment: Across all contacts!

Comment: Managing the max value across all objects inside of each object is not best practice.  It has scaling issues.  What business problem are you trying to solve? (This could be an example of an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Problem: Our contacts send quotes to us. We want to segment each contact based on the average number of quotes they send us daily. In Salesforce, we have an "Average # Quote/day" number formula field, calculated with the input of another field (on the contact object). This number changes daily. We created a "Contact Segment" picklist field on contact object and want each contact segment to dynamically update when daily quote # changes > high/med/low segments based on the % each represents out of the total (across all contact records)>high is top tier, medium is mid tier and low is bottom tier

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly, you will need to do something like the following:

- Create a scheduled batchable (Apex) that runs daily (perhaps after today's quotes are in). Be sure to implement `Database.Stateful`

  - The `start()` method does a query to count the number of quotes received that day, week, month, year, last12 months, etc. Save this in an instance variable of the batchable
  - The `start()` method then does a Select SOQL to choose the Contacts that need to be updated with the count(s) fetched above
  - The `execute()` method will get 200 Contacts at a time and you can use trivial DML to update the Contacts
  - The `finish()` method does nothing.
- With the job, you'll have in every Contact the denominator you will need to then construct a formula field(s) that calculates the tier.  Note this solution defines the tier as of the end of the day, not real-time during the day

If you go this route, and get stuck, post a new question with your code rather than keeping this question/answer going

Comment: Thanks for your response! This will be out of my league so I will have to ask for extra support. I appreciate your help though!